# PostgreSQL: Join 2 tables based on an array (foreign key) column

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, select

I'm using PostgreSQL and I have a table that I'm keeping my users, and in another table, I'm keeping a user's group that contains id and group's name. In the user's table, I have a column that I save each user's group id in an array. Now I want to get all data from users and the name of the groups for each user. How should I do it? here is an example:
user table :

```
user_id  name  roles   
1        bob   [1, 2]   
2        jack  [3]
```

role table:

```
role_id  name
 1       ceo
 2       cto
 3       financial
```

and I expect to have :

```
user_id  name   role_name
 1       bob    CEO, cto
 2       jack   financial
```

Comment: You should probably join them

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the user LJ01 said in the comments, you should join the 2 tables.
If the users and groups tables have the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id BIGINT,
  name TEXT,
  group_ids BIGINT[]
);

CREATE TABLE groups (
  id BIGINT,
  name TEXT
);
```

You can join the tables with the following query:

`SELECT u.*,g.name FROM users u JOIN groups g ON g.id = ANY (u.group_ids);`

So if the users table has the following data:

```
id  name    group_ids
1   Test1   {1,2,3}
2   Test2   {3,4}
```

And there are 4 groups:

```
id  name
1   Group1
2   Group2
3   Group3
4   Group4
```

The result of the query will be

```
1   Test1   {1,2,3} Group1
1   Test1   {1,2,3} Group2
1   Test1   {1,2,3} Group3
2   Test2   {3,4}   Group3
2   Test2   {3,4}   Group4
```

**UPDATE**
The user asked for one row per user with the groups aggregated in a single row. That can be achieved with the following query:

```
  SELECT u.id, u.name,array_agg(g.name) group_names FROM users u JOIN groups g ON g.id = ANY (u.group_ids)
  GROUP BY u.id, u.name;
```

If we execute this query on the example data that is shown on the begining of the answer, we are going to get the following results:

```
u.id u.name  group_names
1    Test1   {Group1,Group2,Group3}
2    Test2   {Group3,Group4}
```

Comment: thanks it's working but it returns all rows that have group_ids. how can the rows which have group_ids = null?

Comment: If you want to return the users with `group_ids = null`, then replace the `JOIN` part with `LEFT JOIN`